# select query will not execute, is my syntax wrong?

Tags: mysql, select

Apparently i have something wrong because this query will not execute, Can anyone see why ?

```
$username=username;

$mysqli = @new mysqli($localhost, $user, $pass, $database);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM player_log WHERE user = '$username'AND log_status=online";
$result = $mysqli->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0){
echo "its works";

}
```

Comment: There should be a space before `AND` in the `WHERE` clause. `$sql = "SELECT * FROM player_log WHERE user = '$username' AND log_status=online";`

Comment: @Ullas: No; a space there is conventional but not necessary. It could be written: `"SELECT*FROM player_log WHERE user='$username'AND log_status=online"` and it would be OK.

Comment: What is the exact error message?  You need to find it and report it, because that will tell you what's wrong.  Chances are that you don't have a column called `online` in your query; you need to embed that in single quotes.

Comment: It also helps not to explicitly silence errors when trying to find out what might be going wrong. Also, how can you tell that the query doesn't execute? On your current test, it could also skip the "it works" part because 0 results were found. Why not try changing the query to `SELECT * FROM player_log WHERE (user = '$username' AND log_status='online') OR 1=1` which would return all rows.

Answer (score 1):

#### Multiple issues see modified code below

Added standard way to call mysqli (space after `$username` is not an issue)

```
$username=username;

$mysqli = @new mysqli($localhost, $user, $pass, $database);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM player_log WHERE user = '$username'AND log_status='online' ";

if ($result = $mysqli->query($sql)){

    printf("Select returned %d rows.\n", $result->num_rows);

    /* free result set */
    $result->close();
    echo "its works";
}
```

Comment: there is actually a space there in my original file, i missed the space when formatting the post here. the issue is not the space

Comment: log_status value needs to be in quotes.

Comment: Besides the above sql syntax changes, i've added the standard php syntax for calling mysqli

Comment: @sdayal I was about to write the same; that does the job.

Comment: There is no need for a space there.  You need spaces to separate words, but symbols don't need to be separated from words by spaces.  Yes, for readability, a space is a good idea, but it is not the reason the query is failing.  Done: _Please remove that fallacious diagnosis so I can remove my downvote._   Not done:  Point out the changes you made in the answer rather than just in the comments, and then I can up-vote.

Comment: Thanks Jonathan, modified the space part.